# 1.5 inch male thread drain coming out of the wall. How do I connect a plastic p trap on it?

Tags: plumbing, drain

[image]

I have the following pipe coming out of the wall. It seems to me that I would need a p trap that screws onto the existing thread but all drain plumbing I have seen so far (e.g.,  https://www.lowes.com/pd/Keeney-1-1-2-in-Plastic-P-Trap/1076241) appears to have the plastic connecting downward (it has its own thread and you use the top part to secure it to the drain). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the rest of that trap or purchase a new one. If you can not find a trap that matches yours you will need to cut the old stuff off and start with a new trap kit. I have found even 30+ year old plumbing matches up to brand new pieces. Take this photo to a plumbing store or big box and they can set you up for 3-15$. The house ghee price if you have to cut and replace the lower for the bend with a nut.

Comment: It *almost* looks like the piece of the trap has a threaded compression coupling that attaches it to the actual drain pipe coming out of the wall. Hard to tell from the one picture, but if that's the case, it'd be as simple as unscrewing that and replacing the entire piece (without any cutting of pipe).

Comment: If it is galvanized it may be screwed on but if plastic pipe normally glued together, can’t tell from that photo but a replacement is probably available.

Comment: I had the rest of the p trap except for the top screwy thingy. I went to the hardware store and tried the selection and found one that screws. Different color of course but 30+ years changes things..not sizes thought.